# Cannot read property 'removeControl' of undefined Jasmine Angular4 FormControl

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Using FormGroup Angular4 i am trying to write test case for remove/add field using formControl. Using  removeControl() of FormGroup in my component getting
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeControl' of undefined** in my test case

```
if (authType.value === 'XXX') {
  restFormGroup.removeControl('username');
} else {
  const userNameControl: FormControl = new FormControl('username', Validators.required);
  restFormGroup.addControl('username', userNameControl);
  restFormGroup.controls['password'].updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

I have imported form modules in my test case as follows

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [XXXComponent],
     imports: [
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      AppMaterialModule,
      NoopAnimationsModule
   ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
 })
  .compileComponents()
  }));

beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(xxxComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   component.xxForm = new FormGroup({});
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });

it('should be created', () => {
   expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

How can i resolve TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeControl' of undefined of FormGroup method, Any help would be great.

Comment: your karma code?

Comment: Its just create component test case.. whether i should add a spy on formGroup  component for removeControl() method i dont know... just updated the code above

Comment: Your restFormGroup must not have a control named 'username' yet. Are you creating this form control oninit in the component?

Comment: @Karthigeyan you can spy and assert the test case. remember to trigger `fixture.detectChanges()` inside the `it` instead of `beforeEach()`

Comment: @Z.Bagley yes i am creating this form field on OnInit based on dropdown form valueChanges condition

Comment: @Aravind added fixture.detectChanges() beforeEach i hope this triggers on each test module.. I dont know how to spy on FormGroup removeControl method....

Comment: @Karthigeyan Read it [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/testing#detectchanges-angular-change-detection-within-a-test) you should move it to test case level inside `it`

Answer (score 1):

I think your restFormGroup is not initialized in the test case. Try initializing the variable inside the it. Something like this,

```
// how it is initialized in the component
component.restFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
```